# Making Radio button and referring to different website on select of this button

Tags: html, radio-button

I have below code generated by the tool automatically.

```
<tr>
<td>
<select name="saw_83262_14" id="saw_83262_14" class="VSelDropDown" onchange="obips.views.ViewSelector.onViewSelChanged('d:dashboard~p:j53qjqgv9msr9rr0~r:4kbop57ejob1s5nu~v:compoundView!1~v:viewSelector!1','saw_83262_14');">
<option value="compoundView!3" selected="">
XYZ</option>
<option value="compoundView!4">
PQR</option>
<option value="compoundView!5">
ABC</option>
<option value="compoundView!2">
MNO</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to extract XYZ , PQR , ABC and MNO from the rendered script and make this available as radio button values in between a section ( and ) and if user click on XYZ it will do a href to : "http://example.com/xyz" as same target location. 
If user click on PQR it will do a href to : "http://example.com/pqr" and so on and so forth ..

How can I achieve this using html + javascript combination ?
thanks and appreciate any help .

Comment: what script is rendering the table row above? it looks like you might be in some kind of front-end/JS framework, what is it? When you say you want radio buttons but also "do a href", do you mean clicking on the radio button opens a new tab, or that there is both a radio button and a link visible? Also, what have you attempted in an effort to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: @haxxxton thanks for taking time to reply on here. Yes you are right , my front end/JS framework is auto generating this as dropdown choice. Idea is to get it from Dropdown to Radio button . Clicking on radio button will not open new tab but will show a div section content from the a href redirect URL . I am not a JS savvy tech person so can't get this worked on how it can be interacted within radio button but I want this kind of functionality .

Answer (score -1):

the code uou are trying will take XYZ as text input
try to use bootstrap i created whole website using bootstrap and it has all features you want and they provides code as well.

Comment: Thanks but what is that website ? I know there is highly interactive bootstrap framework . Are you talking about that ? Sorry I am not JS developer I just want my autogenerated code to work with change in JS